# How to convert from the image coordinates to Cartesian coordinates

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this 3D image generated from the simple code below.

```
% Input Image size
imageSizeY = 200;
imageSizeX = 120;
imageSizeZ = 100;

%# create coordinates
[rowsInImage, columnsInImage, pagesInImage] = meshgrid(1:imageSizeY, 1:imageSizeX, 1:imageSizeZ);

%# get coordinate array of vertices
vertexCoords = [rowsInImage(:), columnsInImage(:), pagesInImage(:)];

centerY  = imageSizeY/2;
centerX  = imageSizeX/2;
centerZ  = imageSizeZ/2;
radius   = 28;

%# calculate distance from center of the cube
sphereVoxels = (rowsInImage - centerY).^2 + (columnsInImage - centerX).^2 + (pagesInImage - centerZ).^2 <= radius.^2;

%# Now, display it using an isosurface and a patch
fv = isosurface(sphereVoxels,0);
patch(fv,'FaceColor',[0 0 .7],'EdgeColor',[0 0 1]);  title('Binary volume of a sphere');
view(45,45);
axis equal;
grid on;
xlabel('x-axis [pixels]'); ylabel('y-axis [pixels]');  zlabel('z-axis [pixels]')
```

I have tried plotting the image with `isosurface` and some other volume visualization tools, but there remains quite a few surprises for me from the plots.

1. The code has been written to conform to the image coordinate system (eg. see: vertexCoords) which is a left-handed coordinate system I presume. Nonetheless, the image is displayed in the Cartesian (right-handed) coordinate system. I have tried to see this displayed as the figure below, but that’s simply not happening.
2. I am wondering if the visualization functions have been written to display the image the way they do.

**Image coordinate system:**
[image: Image coordinate system]

Going forward, there are other aspects of the code I am to write for example if I have an input image `sphereVoxels` as in above, in addition to visualizing it, I would want to find north, south east, west, top and bottom locations in the image, as well as number and count the coordinates of the vertices, plus more.

I foresee this would likely become confusing for me if I don’t stick to one coordinate system, and considering that the visualization tools predominantly use the right-hand coordinate system, I would want to stick with that from the onset. However, I really do not know how to go about this.

**Right-hand coordinate system:**

[image: Right-hand coordinate system]

Any suggestions to get through this?

Comment: do you want to change the axes direction? does `set(gca,'XDir','reverse','YDir','reverse');` at the end of this code work for you?

Comment: Hi, thank you. This actually only changes the direction of an axis, hence only affects the visualization. What i want is a permanent conversion such that if for instance i want to find the pixel value at a location, i would use `P(x,y,z)`, rather than `P(y,x,z)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `meshgrid`, the dimensions `x` and `y` axes are switched (contrary to `ndgrid`). For example, in your case, it means that `rowsInImage` is a `[120x100x200] = [x,y,z]` array and not a `[100x120x200] = [y,x,z]` array even if `meshgrid` was called with arguments in the `y,x,z` order. I would change those two lines to be in the classical `x,y,z` order :

```
[columnsInImage, rowsInImage, pagesInImage] = meshgrid(1:imageSizeX, 1:imageSizeY, 1:imageSizeZ);
vertexCoords = [columnsInImage(:), rowsInImage(:), pagesInImage(:)];
```

Comment: Thank you @G.J. I have tried this before now and it still doesn't give me what i want. I need something that converts the coordinates system from the onset.